# Save list of objects to blob in json format

Tags: c#, json, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage

I am creating a list of objects in C#. I want to save them in proper JSON format on the go in the blob storage container. Currently I am saving them on my local drive and then upload to blob. Two problem I am facing:
1. Json format when I add new objects looks like:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "Name": "Peter",
    "Surname": "Pan"  
  }
] 
[
  {
    "id": "2",
    "Name": "Steve",
    "Surname": "Pan"  
  }
]
```

How may I update my code to make them one array with comma separeted values?

```
[
 {
    "id": "1",
    "Name": "Peter",
    "Surname": "Pan"  
  },
 {
    "id": "2",
    "Name": "Steve",
    "Surname": "Pan"  
  }
]
```

2. Is there a way to save to my blob without first saving the file on my local drive?

```
List<Obj> list= new List<Obj>();

list.Add(new Obj()
{               
Id = "1",               
Name = "Peter",            
Surname = "Pan"
});

// Serialize to JSON output
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(list);     

// write string to file locally
System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"people.json", serializedResult);

//Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with the contents of a local file
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"people.json"))
{
   await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
}
```

Json out has wrong format with new object created being a new array also how to upload this file without saving a copy on my local drive?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a blob storage instead of an Azure table? 
I'm not sure what causes your JSON to appear as a list of lists, but I suggest switching to Json.NET and see if this reproduces.

Comment: I have just swapped to Json.NET and I am getting the same output. I have never used Azure tables that's why I was thinking to use blob.

Comment: Azure tables will allow you store the information without converting it to JSON and query it back by different properties.
Let me know which approach you prefer and I will add some demo code as an answer.

Comment: Seems good I may try the tables. Is the way I create my object stay the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Azure Tables ([Here is a great tutorial with examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/visual-studio/vs-storage-aspnet5-getting-started-tables)) for your use case.
Basically, you will save the data without converting it to JSON first and will be able to query and update specific data without re-uploading the whole file.

Based on the tutorial examples and your code, you'll need to do something like this:

```cs
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(
    new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials(
        "<name>", "<account-key>"), true);

// Create the table client.
CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

// Get a reference to a table named "peopleTable"
CloudTable peopleTable = tableClient.GetTableReference("peopleTable");

await peopleTable.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

TableBatchOperation batch = new TableBatchOperation();

batch.Add(TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(new Obj()
{               
    PartitionKey = "1",
    RowKey = "<SomeOtherIdentifier>",
    Name = "Peter",            
    Surname = "Pan"
}));

IList<TableResult> results = await peopleTable.ExecuteBatchAsync(batch);

// Do what you have to do with the results
```

A **VERY** important note:
Your model (Obj in this case) **must** implement the interface `ITableEntity`, or simply derive from `EntityEntity` object.
This is why your Obj has now the `PartitionKey` and the `RowKey` properties.

The combination of the two properties creates the unique identifier for each row in the Azure Table.

Let me know if you have any more questions. :)